# Problem with request.user.is_authenticated

Tags: python, django

I am writing a simple django view that takes username and password and authenticates it using `authenticate()`. However, after successful authentication, `request.user.is_authenticated` is still `False`.

Here is the code:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['USERNAME']
            password = request.POST['PASSWORD']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None : 
                return HttpResponse(request.user.is_authenticated)
            else :
                return HttpResponse('Login Failed')
    else:
        form = loginform()
    return(render(request,'signup/login.html'))
```

In my version of django, `request.user.is_authenticated` is a attribute not function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = loginform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST['USERNAME']
            password = request.POST['PASSWORD']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None : 
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse(request.user.is_authenticated)
            else :
                return HttpResponse('Login Failed')
    else:
        form = loginform()
    return(render(request,'signup/login.html'))
```

after authenticate don't forget to login user with `login(request, user)` ,doc is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in).

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how I missed the literally next thing in the doc.

Comment: i have doubt. authenticate() should have 3 input parameter, isn't it?  
`user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)`

Comment: no,authenticate(username=username, password=password) is right

Comment: In recent versions of Django (1.11, >2.0 i think) authentication backends should accept request as the first argument. If you look at `django/contrib/auth/__init__.py:64` you should see that `authenticate` takes a request kwarg.  Line 110 in that file includes a deprecation warning, stating that in Django 2.1 `request` keyword argument must be moved to the first positional argument.